# Disable SSH access from docker container to it's host

Tags: ssh, docker, iptables, coreos

I'm running a`CoreOS`  to host some `Docker` containers, and I want to block `SSH` access from containers to the `CoreOS` host, which I guess will be a reasonable matter of security.

I've tried to restrict this access using `/etc/hosts.deny` file or using `iptables`. The problem with this approaches is that they both needs container's IP ranges defined specifically and I can't find a guaranteed way to specify it automatically on all new hosts.

As [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_inspect/) describes, the default network definition for bridge interface is:

```
$ sudo docker network inspect bridge
[
  {
      "name": "bridge",
      "id": "7fca4eb8c647e57e9d46c32714271e0c3f8bf8d17d346629e2820547b2d90039",
      "driver": "bridge",
      "containers": {
          "bda12f8922785d1f160be70736f26c1e331ab8aaf8ed8d56728508f2e2fd4727": {
              "endpoint": "e0ac95934f803d7e36384a2029b8d1eeb56cb88727aa2e8b7edfeebaa6dfd758",
              "mac_address": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
              "ipv4_address": "172.17.0.3/16",
              "ipv6_address": ""
          },
          "f2870c98fd504370fb86e59f32cd0753b1ac9b69b7d80566ffc7192a82b3ed27": {
              "endpoint": "31de280881d2a774345bbfb1594159ade4ae4024ebfb1320cb74a30225f6a8ae",
              "mac_address": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
              "ipv4_address": "172.17.0.2/16",
              "ipv6_address": ""
          }
      }
  }
]
```

Docker documentation also says that it uses [172.17.42.1/16](https://docs.docker.com/v1.7/articles/networking/) for `docker0` interface when it is available (which is also configurable using `-b` option). But I see some of containers own IPs like `10.1.41.2` and it makes it difficult to block them using **hard coded** IP range.

I know about `--icc` option which will effect inter container communication on daemon, and want to find a clean way like this and restrict SSH access from containers to their host.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use iptables to set a firewall rule preventing this.

```
iptables -A INPUT -i docker0 -p tcp --destination-port 22 -j DROP
```

(To be run on the host)

Comment: Thank you I didn't know that it's possible to filter packets by iptables